# Generating a 2D delay-Doppler channel matrix

Tags: digital-communications, delay, doppler, channel, channel-estimation

I was wondering if anyone here has any idea on 2D delay-Doppler channel and how to generate the channel matrix?

Even a hint or a resource would be helpful. I just want to understand and visualize the channel nicely so that I can write a program on my own to generate the 2D channel matrix.

Comment: what do you mean with "channel matrix", specifically? That term often appears in the context of MIMO channels, but you don't seem to care about that.

Comment: By "2D delay-Doppler channel matrix", do you mean the evolution of discrete-time Channel Impulse Response with respect to Doppler spectrum? Mathworks documentation  is a good reference that also cites some good papers. https://mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/fading-channels.html

Comment: @MarcusMüller Dear Marcus, channel matrix need not be associated with MIMO only. If you read the current papers on OTFS you will know what I mean by a 2D channel matrix. The SISO-OTFS input/output relation in delay-Doppler domain is given by Y=H*x+w where H is a M*NXM*N channel matrix and I just wanted to know more about it. I have been able to do it already but still I find it difficult to visualize the delay-Doppler channel for high M and N. Btw, do not again get confused by M and N here with the number of antennas like in a MIMO system. M and N here denotes the delay-Doppler grid size.

Comment: OK, so we're in OTFS territory! It would **really** have been wise to mention that in your question. Can you edit your question to mention it, please? People will instantly know what you're referring to, but they might never read your (very good) comment!